# Challenging Python Code Puzzle: Generating Specific Output - Seeking Help for a Solution

Tags: python

```
for num in range _________:
    if num == ________:
        ___________
    else:
        print(________)
```

Fill-in the blanks with the correct answers to generate the shown output.

```
3
6
12
24
```

I tried many times to solve it using that question but I couldn't do anything. The problem is that I have to fill it with the right answer to generate that output, but nothing comes to my mind as an answer. Can anyone solve it?

I tried to make it work with filling in the blanks but I couldn't, it is hard.

Comment: is there any other instructions or info.

Answer (score 4):

The observation here is that 3, 6, 12, 24 can be written as 3*2<sup>0</sup>, 3*2<sup>1</sup>, 3*2<sup>2</sup>, 3*2<sup>3</sup>.

I have no idea why the `if` case is needed, so I just filled in a dummy condition that is never true:

```
for num in range(4):
    if num == -1:
        pass
    else:
        print(3 << num)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possible solutions to this. It could be more sophisticated, as @trincot has shown, or it could be a primitive approach:

```
for num in ['3\n6\n12\n24']:
    if num == '':
        pass
    else:
        print(num)
```

---

Alternative solution

```
for num in range(1):
    if num == 0:
        print('3\n6\n12\n24')
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Nice (+1). Maybe move that string into the `print` argument, as I understand that `range` must be used in the first line of the code.

Comment: @trincot That was my first idea. I'll add this.